Detergent spilled into lint trap
I was doing laundry and removed the lint trap to clean it before starting the load in the dryer and inadvertently spilled about a normal load size amount of liquid laundry detergent in the opening.   Some of this leaked through the holes into the drum so I will re-wash those clothes.
My question is what to do about the laundry detergent.  Do I need to worry about a fire?   If I pour some water down to get rid of it will that just make it worse?  I don't know how the exhaust is designed exactly...

[Edit] to provide pictures. Lint traps live in different places on different dryers.

Is this a gas or electric dryer?

The problem is laundry detergent is designed to be alkaline. Corrosion is the issue, especially combined with heat and humidity.

As a rule, pouring liquids into electrical appliances that are not supposed to have liquids poured into them is bad. Unplug the power cord.
Pouring more liquid into them is thus generally worse.
Start researching how to take your dryer apart so you can clean it if DIYing it, or call someone if not DIYing it.

I'd argue that clothes dryers are designed to have liquid in them. The water collector in my dryer holds about 5 litres of water when full which has gone all through the machine (probably in gaseous form, which will get into even more places than liquid) on it's way from the clothes.

@SamDean Would it read better if the first sentence said "As a rule, pouring liquids into electrical appliances where they are not supposed to have liquids poured into them is bad." Strictly speaking, my washing machine has lots of water in it, but the manufacturer goes to some effort to keep the wet bits separate from the sparky bits. I imagine the case is the same for a tumble dryer.

@ThaRobster Yes that does read better. The wet humid air goes through the lint trap so I'd say the lint trap is one of the areas designed as a "wet bit".

@SamDean Agreed. I guess this now comes down to individual dryer design. The lint trap on my machine is at the bottom and vents under the drum and out. While it would cause some clumping and nastiness, I wouldn't be overly concerned. The OP's sounds like it must be higher up in the machine as it subsequently leaked in to the drum. From a 'better safe than sorry' point of view, I'd probably still try to investigate it and clean up, and still probably wouldn't put water through it as well.

Putting wet/damp clothes in a dryer is not at all the same as pouring liquid into it. But short yours out if it makes you happy, sure.

Chances are the liquid is puddled in the bottom of the cabinet. That's not likely to be a problem, as all electrical connections are typically above that level. It is possible that there's a plug laying on the floor of the cabinet which has been or could get contaminated. That's still probably not a problem, but it could cause a short and damage. It could even electrify the cabinet, which puts you in danger.
So, unplug it, then look around the cabinet door opening and face panel for screws holding it together. Look for screws allowing you to remove the door. Start taking that apart to get a look inside. Keep track of how you did so for reassembly.
Note that YouTube almost certainly has a video showing this process for your model, and many models are similar.

And you definitely want to look at a manual or for a video, as many have at least one major piece that is non-obvious and (IMHO) intended to make you give up and call an appliance repairman. i.e. the top of my current dryer has screws in the back, but when you remove them the top is firmly stuck at the front with no visible means of attachment. You "just have to know" that a puttyknife or similar thin blade inserted at two points on the front will release an invisible fastener, and only then the top lifts off easily.

I'm not sure you're intended to use a tool on those. It's sometimes just a matter of sliding the top panel forward a bit after removing the screws. Good point, though.
